# Web API GET vs POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I initially setup a Web API (not any expert with web api) and followed someone's tutorial online for passing in parameters to a simple get API call.

I had originally created a GET with query strings but as the tutorial showed how using POST allows me to pass JSON to an class object in POST API parameter, it seemed a good idea.

Later on one developer said this was bad practice? Is it? Should I always use GET instead of POST which in essence is what it should be anyway... a GET call, but I like the idea of passing parameters via an object and avoiding a long API call with query strings.

So:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '\api\getlist\1?param2=yyyy&param3=kikkkk&param4=88' etc   
})
```

or

```
var params = ....

$.ajax({
    url: '\api\getlist\',
    data: params
})
```

What should I do, change the code back to using GET? What about caching?

Comment: Technically you should use `GET` when the enpoint only returns a response and `POST` when you are creating a new record/entity from the posted data. Having said that, for purely practical reasons I sometimes create `POST` endpoints that only retrieve data when I need to send complex data that would result in crazy query strings.

Comment: Ok I do have complex query strings, so it sounds like it's perfectly ok to do so from what you've said. What about caching? Is GET cached and POST isn't?

Comment: The browser may cache GET requests, it won't cache POST requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at the [http documentation in w3c](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html).

`GET` is recommended for reading data and `POST` is used to send information (write operations) into the server.

From client side perspective, you could set in jquery ajax setup, to do not use cache with the follow code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

It will generate a random argument on the async request to make a different request everytime, add a parameter like this: `?_=31312312312`.